# How to show that $\frac1z-\frac{1}{z-1}$ does not have an antiderivative on $0<|z|<1$?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

It seems quite straightforward that $\frac1z-\frac{1}{z-1}$ does not have an antiderivative on $0<|z|<1$, because the singularity at $0$ makes integrals path-dependent. However, I still find it a bit tricky to *prove* this rigorously.

Let $f(z)$ be an analytic fuction on $0<|z|<1$ such that
$$
f'(z)=\frac1z-\frac{1}{z-1}.
$$
Let $z_0$ be a point satisfying $0<|z_0|<1$, and let $\gamma:[0,1]\to \mathbb C$ such that $\gamma(0)=z_0,\gamma(1)=z$. Then,
$$
\int_\gamma f'(z)dz=\int_0^1 f'(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)dt\\
=\int_0^1 \frac{d}{dt}(f(\gamma(t))) dt=f(\gamma(1))-f(\gamma(0))\\
=f(z)-f(z_0),
$$
so if $z=z_0$ then $\int_\gamma f'(z)dz=0$. However, if $\gamma(t)=r e^{2 \pi it}, 0<r<1$, then by residue theorem, $\int_\gamma f'(z)dz=2 \pi i \text{ Res}(f',0)=2 \pi i\neq 0$, which is a contradiction.

Is that a perfect proof?

Comment: looks good - though since $\frac{1}{1-z}$ obviously has the antiderivative $-\log (1-z)$ there (principal branch or just the usual power series $\sum{\frac{z^n}{n}}$) then the problem reduces to showing that $\frac{1}{z}$ has no antiderivative there and that is the classical example of such (and your proof is fine)

Answer (score 1):

Your argumentation is fine. The first part can be generalized: a holomorphic function $f$ in $D$ has an antiderivative if and only if
$$
 \int_\gamma f(z) \, dz = 0
$$
for all closed (rectifiable) paths in $D$.

As you correctly demonstrated, that condition is not satisfied for $f(z) = \frac1z-\frac{1}{z-1}$ in the punctured unit disk.